# Schema registry build failed, Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Build of schema-registry failed at maven-plugin

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor
>   (default-descriptor) on project kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:
>   Execution default-descriptor of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed:
>   syntax error @[1,1] in
>   file:/Users/.../#Kafka_Study/schema-registry/maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/maven/SchemaRegistryMojo.java

Can someone help identify the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to build the schema registry project?

Comment: yes, prior to building schema restutls and commons was build.

Comment: I understand that, but why? You can use the Maven Plugin and all other dependencies without building the projects

Comment: need to build a development version of the schema_registry, being a newbie i am just building as per the instructions. Can you point out if i am missing out some thing?